# Is Frankfurt Stock Exchange building open to visitors?

Tags: frankfurt

I travelled to Frankfurt last week and passed through Boersenplatz one time, but it was late in the day. I couldn't get whether the building is open to visitors at any time.

Is it possible to visit the stock exchange building as a tourist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the building is generally open to visitors, but you have to book in advance with the Visitors Center. For free, you can attend a presentation about the exchange and trading in general, as well as observe the trading floor from a gallery above.

You can find more detailed information on the [exchange website](http://deutsche-boerse.com/dbg-en/about-us/services/visit-the-stock-exchange), along with a phone number to their Visitors Center that you can call during business hours to book a visit.

Comment: That answer exactly gives enough information I was looking for, so accepted.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to visit the Deutsche Börse Group at Börsenplatz 4, Frankfurt/Main.

> **[Deutsche Börse AG’s Visitors Center](http://deutsche-boerse.com/dbg-en/about-us/services/visit-the-stock-exchange)** offers you an opportunity to visit the stock exchange.
>
> To outsiders, the stock exchange automatically evokes images of turbulent floor trading and wildly gesticulating traders who communicate and make deals via hand signals and shouting. This is the impression you get from the movies.
>
> Today Xetra® accounts for more than 90 percent of share trading at all German exchanges. However, it is still worth taking a look at floor trading on the Börse Frankfurt (Frankfurt Stock Exchange).
>
> Services provided by the Visitors Center:
>   - [Introductionary presentation](http://deutsche-boerse.com/dbg-en/about-us/services/visit-the-stock-exchange/introduction-presentation)
>   - [VIP programme](http://deutsche-boerse.com/dbg-en/about-us/services/visit-the-stock-exchange/vip-programme)
>   - [Visitors Gallery](http://deutsche-boerse.com/dbg-en/about-us/services/visit-the-stock-exchange/visitors-gallery)
>
> A visit to the gallery and the introductory presentation are free of charge; the VIP programme costs €125 per group of a maximum of 70 people.
>
> Upon request, presentations are also available in English.
>
> The Visitors Center is open Mondays to Fridays from 9 a.m. to 5 p.m.
>
> **Further information**
>   [Directions Frankfurt [PDF, 1.68 MB]](http://deutsche-boerse.com/blob/2532470/e08dd6d8b55c26bcb769775549fda004/data/directions-frankfurt.pdf)
>
> **Please note:**
>   All offers of the Visitors Center require an advance registration by telephone. Please book the introductory presentation as well as your visit to the Visitors Gallery at least one working day in advance. The VIP programme requires a booking of at least three working days in advance. All visitors must present a valid photo identification to enter our premises.
>
> **Contact Visitors Center**
>   Service times: Mon-Fri, 9 a.m. – 5 p.m. CET
>   Tel: +49-(0) 69-2 11-1 15 15
>   Fax: +49-(0) 69-2 11-1 15 11
>   visitor.center@​deutsche-​boerse.com